# Can a Field class from Java reflection work on any object?

Tags: java, reflection, singleton, field

I am curious if I can store an instance of a Field object and use that on any object I pass to it. I'm doing a ton of reflection work, and I recall reading somewhere that it is unsafe to store a Field object and use that as a singleton (more or less) to quickly access the field from the class.

Is this actually possible, or is what I'm trying to do dangerous or flawed in any way? I made a quick test to check, and it appears to work... but I'm unsure if this test alone actually proves that.

*This assumes we're allowed to access the field and a SecurityException won't be raised.*

---

Code used to test:

```
package test;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Field fa = null;
        Field fb = null;

        for (Field f : Test.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
            switch (f.getName()) {
            case "a":
                fa = f;
                break;
            case "b":
                fb = f;
                break;
            }
        }

        fa.setAccessible(true);
        fb.setAccessible(true);

        Test ta = new Test(5, "test");      
        Test tb = new Test(54, "new string");

        try {
            System.out.println(fa.get(ta) + " " + fa.get(tb) + " " + fb.get(ta) + " " + fb.get(tb));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
class Test {

    private int a;
    private String b;

    public Test(int a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Yields:

```
5 54 test new string
```

Comment: One other option you'd have is to use a `MethodHandle` instead of reflection.

Comment: *I recall reading it is unsafe to store a Field object as a singleton.* Can you find the source? I have never heard this and I don't think there is a reason. Just don't call `setAccessible(true)` and expose the `Field` publicly. Most libraries etc. use caching e.g. [*"The utilities cache reflection data for high performance operation"*](https://code.google.com/p/reflectutils/).

Comment: The Field has the same lifetime as the Class it was obtained from.

Comment: @Radiodef I was looking for it as well since I recall reading it on StackOverflow somewhere as a positively rated/accepted answer. Maybe it was on methods possibly, I'm not sure. I'm going to go searching again and see if it can find it -- if I do I'll post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly fine and it's supposed to work this way. A `Field` refers to a field in a specific **class**, not a specific instance (object) of that class - so you can use it with any instance of the class.

Ofcourse, if the `Field` refers to a field in class `Test`, then you can only use it on objects of type `Test`. You would get an `IllegalArgumentException` if you would try to call `get(Object o)` on the `Field` passing it something else than a `Test` object.

See the API documentation of [`Field.get(Object o)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get-java.lang.Object-).

Answer (score 0):

With reflection you can do pretty much anything, also setting private variables or call private methods from outside the object.
During runtime, this is not checked. It's keywords for the compiler only as far as I'm aware of (I might be wrong on this one, please correct me).

Comment: This sounds like you just read the title without even reading what I actually wrote. Doesn't even answer my question...